# prolog, i have list of structure how to Extract data and return new list of other structure?

Tags: list, prolog

I implementing Family program in prolog i have a problem to implement some rules.

first of all i implement this rule:

```
number_of_children_couple(_list):-
   findall(children(_f,_m,_n),children(_f,_m,_n),_list).
```

return list:

```
19 ?- number_of_children_couple(_list).
_list = [children(mordechai, miriam, 1), children(salax, naima, 1), children(eli, bella, 2), children(..., ..., ...)|...].
```

my problem is how to implement :

```
number_of_children_person(_list28,list_person):-
```

first argument:

```
_list28 = _list  //the above list ,that return from the rule
```

and second argument is :

```
list_person = [children(mordechai, 1), children(salax, 1),children(eli, 2),children(..., ...)|...]
```

and i also use with:

```
%_num is number of children for couple
children(_father,_mother,_num):-
   couple(_mother,_father),
   findall(_child,parents(_mother,_father,_child),_children),
   length1(_children,_num).
```

%_num is number of children for _person

```
children(_person,_num):-
   gender(_person,_),
   findall(_child,parent(_person,_child),_list),
   length1(_list,_num).
```

Comment: To start with findall/3 is definitely not a good idea. Refer to "Art of Prolog" as a good introductory text.

Answer (score 0):

*if* what you want is to drop an argument from children/3 structure, can be done in  a number of ways, the simpler being

```
number_of_children_person([],[]).
number_of_children_person([children(A,_,C)|R],[children(A,C)|T]) :-
   number_of_children_person(R,T).
```

or more succintly

```
number_of_children_person(L3,L2) :-
  findall(children(A,C), member(children(A,B,C),L3), L2).
```

Comment: but i also want in list L2  children(B,C) not only children(A,C).

Comment: i think about something like this:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 'number_of_children_person(L3,L2):-'
  findall(children(A,C), member(children(A,B,C),L3), L4),
  findall(children(B,C), member(children(A,B,C),L3), L5),conc(L4,L5,L2).